# First n elements of an array (which can be nil)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I would like to retrieve the first `n` elements of an array which could be nil and could also have less than n elements. Is there a "swifty" way to do it?

This works:

```
n=2
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
array.prefix(upTo: 2) // [1,2]
```

But I also want it to work with

```
array = [1] //I want to get [1]
```

or

```
array = nil //I want nil as return
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying that the array can be nil, or that the elements in the array can be nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Optional.map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) and [`Sequence.prefix`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2886011-prefix):

```
let n = 2
let array: [Int]? = [1,2,3,4,5]
let firstN = array.map { Array($0.prefix(n)) }
```

The result `firstN` is an optional array. It is `nil` if `array`
is `nil`, and an array with at most `n` elements of the given array
otherwise.

If an [`ArraySlice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice)
result is good enough for your purpose then it can be
simplified to

```
let firstN = array?.prefix(n)
```

as @Duncan suggested.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler and easier to read to use `let firstN = array?.prefix(3)?` Granted, that returns an `ArraySlice` rather than an array, but that is fine for most use-cases.
`

Comment: @DuncanC: Sure! The question asked for an array, that's why I suggested that code. But you are completely right: if an array slice is good enough then it can be simplified.

Comment: Using `map()` on the `Optional` is a very elegant solution, once you understand what it's doing. (Voted)